How to plug 1/2" diam. hole in 1950s South Florida cement block house wall from old ATT wiring
I'm ready to remove an old data wire/cable from ATT in a second bedroom.  Doing so would leave a hole to the outside of the house.  What could I use to plug it?
The house is down south and is made of cement blocks, I think, and from the mid-1950s.
The cable is about 1/2" in diameter.  The hole/bore is about 9" through from inside to outside.

concrete ......

The outside surface, you want mortar or hydraulic cement to seal up.
